# Parsing a foursquare KML venue feed with simpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml, kml, foursquare

I am trying to parse a KML venue feed from foursqare with simpleXML but I cannot get the nested-in-desctription venue url. It looks like simpleXML strips it.

In detail:

The foursqare kml feed looks like this:

```
<kml>
 <Folder>
    <name>foursquare checkin history for X</name>
    <description>foursquare checkin history for X</description>
    <Placemark>
       <name>somevenuename</name>
       <description>@<a href="/v/somevenueurl">somevenuename</a>- a foursqareshout!</description>
       <updated>Wed, 02 Nov 11 17:00:05 +0000</updated>
       <published>Wed, 02 Nov 11 17:00:05 +0000</published>
       <visibility>1</visibility>
       <Point>
         <extrude>1</extrude>
         <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode> 
         <coordinates>xx.xxxxxx,yy.yyyyyy</coordinates>
       </Point>
    </Placemark>
    etc ...
```

My call to simpleXMl is ... well, simple:
 `$venue_items = simplexml_load_file($venue_kml_file);`
Any ideas who to preserve the html in `description`?

Comment: Pretty difficult this, because the KML is wrong (I would say, at least) - the content of `<description>` should be CDATA if it can contain HTML. I know this doesn't really help, but it might be worth bringing this up with the feed provider, since they are making consumers lives a lot more difficult by not doing this...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I might as well do it but it will not provide me with a solution any time soon. :\

Comment: how about adding the CDATA wrapper yourself inside the <description> tag before passing it to simplexml_load_file()?

Comment: Yes, since I cannot deal with the issue directly with simpleXML, it will require some kind of preprocessing eventually.

Answer (score 2):

They're right. This is invalid XML. However, I wrote a workaround for you using regex. It may be a bit hacky, but you can only make due with what you've been given, so here it is:

```
$xml_string = <<<XML_STRING
<kml>
 <Folder>
    <name>foursquare checkin history for X</name>
    <description>foursquare checkin history for X</description>
    <Placemark>
       <name>somevenuename</name>
       <description>@<a href="/v/somevenueurl">somevenuename</a>- a foursqareshout!</description>
       <updated>Wed, 02 Nov 11 17:00:05 +0000</updated>
       <published>Wed, 02 Nov 11 17:00:05 +0000</published>
       <visibility>1</visibility>
       <Point>
         <extrude>1</extrude>
         <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode> 
         <coordinates>xx.xxxxxx,yy.yyyyyy</coordinates>
       </Point>
    </Placemark>
 </Folder>
 <Folder>
    <name>foursquare checkin history for X</name>
    <description>foursquare checkin history for X</description>
    <Placemark>
       <name>somevenuename</name>
       <description>@<a href="/v/somevenueurl222">somevenuename</a>- a foursqareshout!</description>
       <updated>Wed, 02 Nov 11 17:00:05 +0000</updated>
       <published>Wed, 02 Nov 11 17:00:05 +0000</published>
       <visibility>1</visibility>
       <Point>
         <extrude>1</extrude>
         <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode> 
         <coordinates>xx.xxxxxx,yy.yyyyyy</coordinates>
       </Point>
    </Placemark>
 </Folder>
</kml>    

XML_STRING;


preg_match_all( '%<Placemark>(.*?)</Placemark>%s', $xml_string, $placemarks, PREG_SET_ORDER );
for( $x = 0; $x < sizeof($placemarks); $x++ ){
    preg_match_all('%<description>(.*?)</description>%s', $placemarks[$x][1], $descriptions, PREG_SET_ORDER );
    for( $y = 0; $y < sizeof($descriptions); $y++ ){
        echo $descriptions[$y][1];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thank you @Homer6  I was not paying attention to stackoverflow for a few days and missed this. I had to use a workaround in my project, so I am passed this need, but I will store it for future use.